# pre-fill select box using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu

In this example the pre defined item not selected by default. Please help to achieve this.

```
<button ng-click="addRow()">Add Row</button>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="row in rows">
      <select kendo-drop-down-list ng-model="row.selected" ng-init="row.selected = row.choosenItem" ng-options="item.name for item in list | filter:notUsed(row)"></select>
      <button ng-click="deleteRow(row)">X</button>
    </li>
  </ul>

var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
```

In the data ($scope.rows) item selected in row.choosenItem property. Still the selectbox not filled with choosenItem.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.list = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "one"
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: "Two"
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: "Three"
  }, {
    id: 4,
    name: "Four"
  }, {
    id: 5,
    name: "Five"
  }, {
    id: 6,
    name: "Six"
  }];
  $scope.rows = [{
    choosenItem: {
      id: 2,
      name: "Two"
    },
    label: "row 1",
    selected: 2
  }, {
    choosenItem: {
      id: 4,
      name: "Four"
    },
    label: "row 2",
    selected: 4
  }];

  function byID(member) {
    return member.choosenItem.id;
  }

  $scope.notUsed = function(row) {
    return function(item) {
      return item.id === row.choosenItem.id || !_.indexBy($scope.rows, byID)[item.id];
    }
  };

  $scope.addRow = function addRow() {
    $scope.rows.push({
      choosenItem: {},
      label: "row "+($scope.rows.length+1),
      selected: 0
    })
  };

  $scope.deleteRow = function deleteRow(row) {

  };

  $scope.onSelectChange = function onSelectChange(row){
    row.choosenItem = _.findWhere($scope.list, {'id': parseInt(row.selected)});
  };
});
```

[Example code here](https://plnkr.co/edit/DeUAyHKWWd4ptmndcm46?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, when using `ngOptions` the syntax is `value as text for item in array` - so keeping that in mind, define your value:

```
ng-init="row.selected = row.choosenItem.id" ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in list"
```